# When do you use () to invoke function?

Tags: reactjs

beginner react user here, I'm sorry if this sounds really stupid but I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

I'm using onChange for example,

`onChange={functionName}` vs `onChange(functionName())` vs `onChange(() => functionName())`

when do we know which to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onChange={functionName}` if the `functionName` can be called without a calling context - that is, if it doesn't reference `this` inside it, or if its `this` has been bound (for example, with `this.functionName = this.functionName.bind(this)` in the constructor, or if the function is declared with a class field).

If the `this` context needs to be preserved, then either use one of the above methods, or use the third method listed in your question:

```
onChange(() => this.functionName())
```

Using that method ensures that `functionName` gets invoked with a calling context of `this`, the class instance, which is necessary if the function references `this` inside it.

The second option:

```
onChange(functionName())
```

is pretty rare - it's only for when you have a function that *returns* another function, for example:

```
const makeFn = arg => () => {
  console.log(arg);
};
// ...
<button onClick={makeFn('foo')} />
```

The above calls `makeFn` when the component is rendered, which returns *another* function which is used as the click listener.

Answer (score 0):

both `onChange={functionName}` and `onChange(() => functionName())` are OK, `onChange` expect a function and will invoke the function when the event happen instead of the result of a function

`functionName` is a valid function `() => functionName()` declare a new inline function while `functionName()` is the result of the function

Answer (score 0):

Considering above/below answers and Adding one more important point: There's a performance issue as well.

`onChange(() => this.functionName())` -> This will always create a new function whenever onChange triggered which leads to memory leakage by creating anonymous functions.

`onChange={functionName}` -> This will pass just reference to onChange and it won't create any new functions.